# How to pass a JSON data from React to Django using POST request?

Tags: reactjs, django, fetch

I have a React frontend which has a state variable that contains an array. I want to pass this state variable onClick to my Django's `views.py`. What I have so far is something like this:

**App.js**

```js
const [dataSource, setDataSource] = useState([]); // Where the data is stored in

const requestOptions = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify(dataSource),
};

const handleSubmit = () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/insert", requestOptions);
};

<Popconfirm onConfirm={handleSubmit}>
    <Button>Submit</Button>
</Popconfirm>
```

**views.py**

```py
def insert(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
           json_data = request.POST.get() 
           # I'm not sure what should I be putting as a parameter for .get() method

     return render(request, 'frontend/index.html')
```

**urls.py**

```py
...
urlpatterns = [
     ...
     path('insert/', views.insert),
     ...
]
```

Am I using the right approach? If it's right, what should I be passing as parameters to the `get()` method?

*P.s. I'm not using DRF for this approach and I'm building the app where Django and React is in one app (not separate) where the frontend is an app of Django.

Comment: `post` method suppose to end in  `/`. And check the request.body to receive raw data and then you can use json.loads to convert to dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things before the problem. First you should not use `insert` as your view name its against the rest conventions, for more [read this doc](https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/)

Second make it `fetch("http://localhost:8000/insert/", requestOptions);`

Third when you want to get the body all you need to do is

```
import json
    data = json.loads(request.body)
```

and you will get the post data as json in your hand